# What's the CSS combinator for (foo bar, foo biz, foo tar, foo boo { })?

Tags: css

What's the CSS combinator or short-hand for writing this ruleset?

```
foo bar, 
foo biz, 
foo gaz > boo, 
foo tar {
 ...
}
```

I am pretty sure I read on the MDN somewhere that there was one. Was it:

```
foo (bar, biz, gaz > boo, tar) {
}
```

I can't find that page. Could you please link to it?

Comment: There isn't one. You might be thinking of SCSS or any number of other transpile-to-CSS languages.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors - here you go

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is CSS PreProcessing.

In SCSS your code will be like this

```
.foo {
  .bar, .biz, .gaz > .boo, .tar {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

In SASS Your code will be like this

```
.foo
  .bar, .biz, .gaz > .boo, .tar
    color: red
```